# html_nodes to scrape text with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

Actually I'm trying to get the sku number of this code (this number -> 111653240199):

```
<body>
 <div id= ‘a page’>
   <div class =”spaui-squishy-container” style=”display:table:table-row;”>
    <div class =”spaui-squishy-inner-container” style=”display:table-row;”>
     <div class =”spaui-squishy-content” style=display:table-cell;”>
      <div id=”myi-table-center” class=”a-container Madagascar-main-body”>
       <div id=”miytable” class=”mt-container clearfix””>
        <div class="mt-content clearfix">
         ::before
          <div class="mt-content clearfix">
           ::before
            <table class="a-bordered a-horizontal-stripes  mt-table">
             <tbody>
               <tr id="head-row" class="mt-head">
               <tr id="MTExNjUzMjQwMTk5" data-delayed-dependency-data="{&quot;MYIService&quot;(…)
                <td id= MTExNjUzMjQwMTk5-sku” data-colum=”sku” data-row=” MTExNjUzMjQwMTk5”>
                 <div class="mt-combination mt-layout-block">
                  <div id="MTExNjUzMjQwMTk5-sku-sku" data-column="sku" data-row="ExNjUzMjQwMTk5">
                   <div class="clamped wordbreak">
                    <div class="mt-text mt-wrap-bw"> 
                     <span class="mt-text-content mt-table-main">
                      111653240199
                     </span>
```

My script in R has this:

```
  dades<-read_html(url)

  id<-dades %>% html_nodes("#mt-table-container.clearfix .mt-link.mt-wrap-bw.clamped.wordbreak a") %>% html_text()
```

But the result is -> character empty

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help and your time :-)

Comment: Could you paste a complete (yet minimal) snipet from your html?

Comment: I've paste more code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with the following:

```
library(rvest)
read_html(text) %>%
  html_nodes('div.mt-text') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  #the following removes whitespaces
  trimws()

  #[1] "111653240199"
```

Comment: Happy to help :)